# How can I delete lines in which the name appears only once?

Tags: r, for-loop

Hello I would like to delete the lines where the name occurs only once.
I simplified the problem:
in the column "Name" comes "ananas", "bike", "lemon" only once and I would like to delete these lines.

My data looks like this:

[image]

Comment: one option is `df[duplicated(df$a) | duplicated(df$a, fromLast = TRUE), ]` where `a` is your first column and `df` is dataframe.

Comment: df1 <- data.frame(A = c("Ted", "John", "Alice", "Mo", "John", "Mo"),
                  B = c(10, 4, 5, 2, 5, 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1[duplicated(df1$A),]

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible solutions for this problem. If you want to solve it in the `tidy` way I propose this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df = tribble(~name, ~value,
        "ananas", 42,
        "apple", 4,
        "apple", 69,
        "bike", 70)

df %>% 
  add_count(name) %>% 
  filter(n!=1) %>%
  select(-n)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 apple     4
2 apple    69
```

Comment: Thank you fast response!